# BLE app with React Native vs Native Platforms

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am looking for pros and cons of creating a BLE mobile application with ReactNative or Native Platforms(both iOS and Android).

Which approach I should follow? Can anyone share their experience with ReactNative?
I have worked with both native platforms, and it has given me good results, but for my new project I am considering ReactNative, as it has single code base and it comparatively takes less efforts than working on iOS and Android separately.

Are these advantages available for BLE apps as well? Or it may have issues with performance and maintenance as well?

Answer (score 1):

Making an app using BLE with RN (react-native) is not difficult, and I didn't feel it was much slower than native app. (but it really depends on how big is your app).

Then yes, I would say that RN is faster for making your BLE app.

However you have to be aware : if you are using several native function, RN might be a bit tricky and could become a nightmare for debug.

PS : I made an app with [this BLE lib](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am more worrying about the different devices and OS dependencies we have to handle in Android. Sometimes in native platform as well it become tricky. In my case we would be doing standard operations like scanning, connecting, reading/writing.

Comment: if it's standard BLE operations, I would say RN might be faster (only one app for android and iOS)